# for-loop and delimeters

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I need e fast way to insert a few rows of structured data in a bat file
I've used an array called myarray to scan and "read" my values but it does not work and i don't understand why
This is my code:

```
@echo off
set myarray[1]=myfield1#myfield2#mysubfield31;mysubfield32#myfield4
for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=#" %%a in ('echo %myarray[1]%') do (
    echo field1 is %%a
    echo field2 is %%b
    echo field3 is %%c
    echo field4 is %%d
    for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=;" %%k in ('echo %%c') do (
        echo subfield3 is %%k
        echo subfield3 is %%l       
    )
)
```

the output is like this:

```
field1 is myfield1
field2 is myfield2
field3 is mysubfield31 mysubfield32
field4 is myfield4
subfield3 is mysubfield31 mysubfield32
subfield3 is
```

why i can't obtain simply:

```
subfield3 is mysubfield31 
subfield3 is mysubfield32
```

where is the ";" used as delimeter in the second for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
@echo off
set myarray[1]=myfield1#myfield2#mysubfield31;mysubfield32#myfield4
for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=#" %%a in ("%myarray[1]%") do (
    echo field1 is %%a
    echo field2 is %%b
    echo field3 is %%c
    echo field4 is %%d
    for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=;" %%k in ("%%c") do (
        echo subfield3 is %%k
        echo subfield3 is %%l       
    )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=#" %%a in ("%myarray[1]%") do (
```

may work a tad better...

Comment: I edited the `%array[1]%` name so people can try the code and not get stuck scratching their head.  It took me many edits and cursing microsoft random cmd behaviour before I saw it. :)

Answer (score -1):

That's [documented behavior](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71247), the semicolon is treated as whitespace (not by the `for` loop, but by the subshell executing the `echo` command). This causes the semicolon to be replaced with a space, so that `echo field3 is %%c` produces the output `field3 is mysubfield31 mysubfield32`. Either remove `delims=;` from the inner loop, so it uses the default delimiters (space and tab), or choose a different delimiter character, and your script should work as expected. Note, however, that relying on the default delimiters in the inner loop may produce undesired results, when fields of the nested "array" contain spaces.

Proof:

1. Demonstration of the root cause:

   ```
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo.a#b;c#d^|find ";"') do echo _%%a_
   ```

   Output: none (i.e. no semicolon found in the echoed string)

   ```
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo.a#b;c#d^|find " "') do echo _%%a_
   ```

   Output: `_a#b c#d_`

   Apparently this applies to all [delimiter characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) (`,`, `;`, `=`, space and tab), since I could reproduce this behavior with each of them.
2. Simplified script with an input string `a#b;c#d`:

   ```
   @echo off
   set "foo=a#b;c#d"
   for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ('echo %foo%') do (
     echo field1 is %%a
     echo field2 is %%b
     echo field3 is %%c
     for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=;" %%k in ('echo %%b') do (
       echo subfield3 is %%k
       echo subfield3 is %%l       
     )
   )
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   field1 is a
   field2 is b c
   field3 is d
   subfield3 is b c
   subfield3 is
   ```

   Note the space between `b` and `c` in 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> line of the output.
3. Same script as 2., but with `delims=;` removed from the inner loop:

   ```
   @echo off
   set "foo=a#b;c#d"
   for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ('echo %foo%') do (
     echo field1 is %%a
     echo field2 is %%b
     echo field3 is %%c
     for /f "tokens=1-2" %%k in ('echo %%b') do (
       echo subfield3 is %%k
       echo subfield3 is %%l       
     )
   )
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   field1 is a
   field2 is b c
   field3 is d
   subfield3 is b
   subfield3 is c
   ```

   Note that the nested "array" `b;c` (from the variable `%foo%`) is now processed into the correct output (lines 4 and 5). This is, because spaces and tabs are the default delimiters in `for /f` loops.
4. Same script as 2., but using `+` as the delimiter for the nested "array":

   ```
   @echo off
   set "foo=a#b+c#d"
   for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ('echo %foo%') do (
     echo field1 is %%a
     echo field2 is %%b
     echo field3 is %%c
     for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=+" %%k in ('echo %%b') do (
       echo subfield3 is %%k
       echo subfield3 is %%l       
     )
   )
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   field1 is a
   field2 is b+c
   field3 is d
   subfield3 is b
   subfield3 is c
   ```

   Note that the 2<sup>nd</sup> output line no longer contains the bogus space, and that, again, the nested "array" is processed correctly (lines 4 and 5).

---

For completeness: a better solution would be to drop the `echo` altogether and simply loop on a double quoted string, as [foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17392023/1630171) and [Peter Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391637/1630171) suggested, because it avoids the issue entirely.

```
@echo off
set "foo=a#b;c#d"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ("%foo%") do (
  echo field1 is %%a
  echo field2 is %%b
  echo field3 is %%c
  for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=;" %%k in ("%%b") do (
    echo subfield3 is %%k
    echo subfield3 is %%l       
  )
)
```

Another solution, proposed by dbenham, would be to enable delayed expansion and have the variable expanded at runtime:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "foo=a#b;c#d"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=#" %%a in ('echo !foo!') do (
  echo field1 is %%a
  echo field2 is %%b
  echo field3 is %%c
  for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=;" %%k in ('echo %%b') do (
    echo subfield3 is %%k
    echo subfield3 is %%l       
  )
)
```

An even better solution, however, would be to drop batch entirely and switch to a language that actually supports arrays, e.g. PowerShell.

Comment: Wrong! The semicolon is treated as delimiter _in plain (no /F option) FOR command_. In `FOR /F` command the delimiters are precisely the ones placed in `delims=...` option.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=;" %j in ("a;b;c;d") do echo %j %k %l %m`

Comment: You are right that it is a delimiter in certain cases, but you are wrong to suggest removing it from the "delims=;" as a solution.

Comment: Did you look at my solution where `;` is working as a delimiter?

Comment: Your proof works because of the child cmd called to echo the variable, and that is where the `;` is being treated as a delimiter. If you enclose the variable in double quotes it will remain in the for loop.

Comment: BTW, it's not a weird anything of the echo command.  It's what happens when the semicolon and equals is used unquoted on the command line, and even when calling a label, and I've been aware of it since MSdos days (funny thing too, the MSKB article you quote only lists MSdos products as being affected, but it still applies in modern Windows).  The article is poorly describing the effect.

Comment: You advocated removing the semicolon and that may not be possible in the OP's data set.  Your solution was that the semicolon can't be used in a "delims=" is incorrect and hence the downvote.  You were incorrect and are now just arguing when solutions and examples have been posted showing `;` being used in "delims="

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: One more time: the semicolon is **NOT** treated as whitespace in `for /F` command; the article in your link does **NOT** refer to `for /F` command, but to Batch file parameters (and FOR **with NO /F option** by extension). It is funny that in the point 2. of your example you said "Note that the nested "array" `b;c` is now processec correctly" when the value being processed is `b c`! This problem is NOT related to the processing of `for` command in any way, but to the generation of `b c` string with the semicolon removed.

Comment: Copied from the first line in your answer above: "That's documented behavior, the semicolon is **treated** as whitespace". You had not said "replaced" until your last comment (you may achieve a find in this page to confirm it). Of course, the whole topic is about `for /f` command! Isn't it?

Comment: Please look at the output, the OP got: `subfield3 is mysubfield31 mysubfield32`. As you can see (and I tested it also) the semi colon is removed. And, moreover, if you add a "space" to delims `"tokens=1-9 delims=; "`, the output is now as expected. **But** if you add a "tab" to the semi colon, both tokens appear again at the same line ! Because of this confusing behavior I deleted my downvoting again. But please note, this behaviour doesn't belong _mainly_ to the `for /f` loop.

Comment: @Endoro Most likely the tab is also replaced with a space, since it's a [delimiter character](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) just like `,`, `;`, `=` and space.

Comment: I think, the "space" is (in this case) a _special delimiter_. If you add one of the `,=;` `\t` to the (first) semicolon, the output appears on the same line (also with eg. an `M`...). **Only** with a space it appears as expected by the OP on two lines.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - You are on the correct track that the `;` is treated as a space when processed within the FOR /F IN() clause. But your proposed solution to simply change the delimiter completely misses the mark. Your "solution" happens to work because none of the data fields contain a space. But it will fail if they do contain spaces. A proper solution preserves the `;`. Ideally use a string instead of a command: `in ("%myarray[1]%")`. Or use delayed expansion with a command: `in ('echo !myarray[1]!')`

Comment: @Endoro I don't follow. If I use any of the 5 delimiter characters as `X` in `a#bXc#d`, they are replaced with a space. If I use other characters (like the uppercase `M` you named as an example), the code works just fine. Of course you'll always have to adjust `delims=` in the inner loop to the respective character used.

Comment: @dbenham I openly admit that foxidrive proposed a better solution.

Comment: @dbenham it seems to be a parsing issue, if `delayed expansion` can avoid it?

Comment: @Endoro - It absolutely is a parsing issue dealing with how FOR /F parses the IN() clause. The `;` can be preserved by escaping it as `^;`, but that is often not practical.